# Convert MySQL number into currency via php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am pulling a number of out a MySQL database, at the moment it has no decimal formatting.

Is it possible to do this via php once it have been selected from the database via a SELECt function?

I would like it to convert from 2500 to £25.00?

Most likely very simple I just cant get my head around it!

Thanks

Comment: money_format() or number_format(), the manual is quite useful for such things.

Comment: Why wouldn't you store your amounts as a decimal instead of an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [money_format](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) and [number_format](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Note that `money_format` only works on systems that support the C library function `strfmon` (Windows does not). Otherwise you'll need to use `number_format` or format it through SQL.

Comment: Thanks webbiedave! Much appreciated!

Comment: You're very welcome. Please upvote and/or checkmark when you can :)

Answer (score 1):

[number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for the win!

```
number_format($row['price'] / 100, 2, '.', ' ')
```

Comment: How does number format work if the number i'm pulling out is part of a SELECT query?!     <?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT price FROM stock WHERE price='coat'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['price'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
?> I cant seem to get it to fit around the "echo $row['price'];" part! Thanks!!

Comment: `$row['price']` has the number. `number_format( $row[ 'price' ] / 100, 2, '.', ' ' )`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use MySQL for this task before bothering PHP: [FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format)
It has the huge advantage of the usage of the mysql locale and it doesn't require extra resources from PHP (which are minimal; but aren't we all minimalists?)

Answer (score 0):

I use [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) for that. Here's the codez:

```
$value = 2500;
$value = $value / 100;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
$value = money_format("%.2n", $value);
echo $value;
```

Output:

```
£25.00
```